# I can't open links neither in Okular, MuPDF nor xpdf

Tags: pdf, okular, mupdf

Is it a bug in viewers or a property that if I click a link in a pdf, nothing happens in Okular and MuPDF outputs "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console"? xPDF outputs

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-normal--12-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-times-bold-i-normal--20-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-times-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1" to type FontStruct
Syntax Error: Couldn't create a font for 'RXAUES+CMR10'
Syntax Error: Couldn't create a font for 'EJASTL+CMR7'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I thought that they will open the WWW-browser. Here is my test file: (I know it is silly to use the package Finnish babel in English document but I just made a quick test file for to demostrate.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
See also \href{http://www.google.com/}{Google}.
\end{document}
```

compiled by `pdflatex test.tex`. Compilation gave

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, et
hiopic, farsi, arabic, pinyin, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, slovak,
 czech, danish, dutch, usenglishmax, ukenglish, finnish, french, basque, ngerma
n, german, swissgerman, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, german-x-2012-05-30, monogreek, g
reek, ibycus, ancientgreek, hungarian, bengali, tamil, hindi, telugu, gujarati,
 sanskrit, malayalam, kannada, assamese, marathi, oriya, panjabi, italian, lati
n, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, nynorsk, bokmal, indonesian, e
speranto, coptic, welsh, irish, interlingua, serbian, serbianc, slovenian, friu
lan, romansh, estonian, romanian, armenian, uppersorbian, turkish, afrikaans, i
celandic, kurmanji, polish, portuguese, galician, catalan, spanish, swedish, th
ai, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2009/07/02 v2.20.1
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/finnish.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./test.out) (./test.out) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] (./test.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb
>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 19384 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: I tried your pdflatex example with Okular and it worked… 13.10 on KDE. And xpdf crashes for all PDFs for me.

Comment: Does `xdg-open "http://google.com"` work? If that's failing, your session doesn't have a set browser for some reason or other.

Comment: @Oli Yes. `xdg-open` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that works on my computer was to upgrade Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04.